# Count occurrences of a value in a Series

Tags: python, pandas

I am newbie to Python. I am reading a csv file (with 3 columns: lib, imports, import_tuples). How can I count the number of occurrences of a value appears in the second column in the the column?

Example:

```
lib,imports,import_tuples 
lib1,"[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]","[[5, 1, 2], [2,1,3],[2, 4, 1]]" 
lib2,"[4, 65, 99, 100]","[[4, 65, 100], [100, 4],[99, 65]]"

Expected Output (for lib1)
0 1 2 3 4 5
0 3 3 1 1 1
```

---

```
import pandas
from collections import Counter
df = pandas.read_csv('temp_data.csv')
myList = second.values.T.tolist()

c = df["import_tuples"].str.split(',').apply(Counter)
data = pandas.DataFrame({n: c.apply(lambda x: x.get(n, 0)) for n in myList})
data =  c.to_frame()
```

Comment: "the number of occurrences of a value appears in the second column in the the column" - what does this sentence mean? Sorry, can't grok it.

Comment: This is too broad as it stands, you are storing lists as a string representation so you need to sort that out first, then you have to reconstruct your value counts, can you attempt this first

Comment: for each value in the 2nd column (0,1,2,3,4,5), i want to count their occurrences in column 3. For example, the value'0' in the 2nd column, appears 0 times in the third column, whereas the value '1' in the 2nd column appears 3 times in the 3rd column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pandas.Series.str.findall()` to extract the numbers from the `strings` and then use `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
df['imports'] = df.imports.str.findall(r'\d+')
df['import_tuples'] = df.import_tuples.str.findall(r'\d+')
df['imports_counted'] = df.apply(lambda x: {i: Counter(x.import_tuples).get(i) for i in x.imports}, axis=1)

    lib             imports                 import_tuples  \
0  lib1  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]   [5, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4, 1]   
1  lib2    [4, 65, 99, 100]  [4, 65, 100, 100, 4, 99, 65]   

                                     imports_counted  
0  {'2': 3, '5': 1, '0': None, '3': 1, '4': 1, '1...  
1               {'99': 1, '4': 2, '100': 2, '65': 2}
```

Comment: The count should be based on the whole number, e.g., 100 appears 2 times in the column 'import_tuples'.

Comment: this is better than my solution, thanks! : `f = open('temp_data_res.csv','w')
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    source = row['lib']
    tuples = row['import_tuples']
    c= tuples.split(',')
    ns = []
    for l in c:
        z= l.translate(None,''.join(chars_to_remove))
        ns.append(int(z))
    od = Counter(ns)
    for key, value in sorted(od.items()):
        print source, " ",key, " ", value`